# Change the hsv value of an image in python

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have an image which is converted to HSV using opencv.

I want to conver the overall V value in HSV to 200, is there anyway.

I used the following code to convert the image to hsv and split into h,s,v

```
image = cv2.imread('../images/test/image_1.jpg',cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(image)

image = cv2.merge([h,s,v])
out = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cv2.imshow('image',out)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is this line.

```
image[:,:,2] = 200
```

This changes the V value to 200.

Your final program should look like.

```
image = cv2.imread('../images/test/image_1.jpg')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

image[:,:,2] = 200 # Changes the V value

out = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cv2.imshow('image',out)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: "You are reading HSV" is **not** true. You need to load a bgr image and explicitly convert to hsv. "cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV" as argument of inshow doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Much better... also, no need to clutter the code with all stuff you **can't** do ;)

Comment: Understood. Thanks a bunch for showing me the SO etiquette! :D